# How to get BOTH pagination & modal windows to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, pagination, magnific-popup

I use "[pagination.js](https://pagination.js.org/)" for pagination, and "[Magnific Popup.js](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)" for iFrame (modal window).
(iFrame (modal window) was exactly the same situation even though [iziModal.js](http://izimodal.marcelodolce.com), so I think that the modal window side anything is ok..)

---

### Problem

Simply put, the problem is that only one or the other works, for now.

When I try to work both pagination and modal window:

[image: When I try to work both pagination and modal window]

In this way, pagination works but iFrame (modal window) doesn't work.

...

When I comment out the following code:

[image: When I comment out the following code]

In this way, pagination doesn't work, but iFrame (modal window) does.

Hmm.. It's a problem.
I need **both** pagination and iframe (modal window). I want both to work.

---

### Code causing the conflict:

Commenting out this part of the pagination code will make the iFrame (modal window) work.
So I thought this was the cause of the conflict.

```
/*  pagination  */
function tpl(data) {
  var html = '';
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    html += '<section class="item">' + item + '</section>';
  });
  return html;
}
// ↑ this part or

$(function() {
  var len = $('.item').length;

  $('#no-p').pagination({
    dataSource: function(done) {
      var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var $item = $('.item').get(i);
        if ($item) result.push($item.innerHTML);
      }
      done(result);
    },
    pageSize: 8,
    showPageNumbers: false,
    showNavigator: true,
    autoHidePrevious: true,
    autoHideNext: true,

    callback: function(data, pagination) {
      var html = tpl(data);
      $('#items').html(html);
    }
    // ↑ iFrame will not be executed unless this part is deleted

  });
});
```

---

I created a demo that actually works. -> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/49qmeoua/13/)

Could you please give me a hand? TT

Comment: I tried with removing the commented code. I see this error in the browser console.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: @NoughT Yes. However I have no idea what "index0f" is..
But I feel that it is not related much.
Because also in iziModal.js it will be the same situation (only one or the other works), but the error doesn't appear. [In the case of iziModal - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/41kLsf67/49/)